# EPPlus - very slow adding multiple images in a loop

Tags: c#, epplus

I have big problem with EPPlus. When I create simple Excel file with 20 images from local resource (disk C:) - everything is OK - it lasts ~3 second. But when I try to do it with >200 pictures - I have to wait ~20 sec to generate file. With 500 items I have to wait ~4 minutes... Why? What I can do to fix that problem?
That's my code:

```
            Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
            string name = "pic" + rowIndex.ToString() + columnIndex.ToString();
            using (ExcelPicture picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(name, image)) 
            {
                image.Dispose();
                picture.From.Column = columnIndex;
                picture.To.Column = columnIndex;

                picture.From.Row = rowIndex;
                picture.To.Row = rowIndex;

                picture.From.ColumnOff = Pixel2MTU(3);
                picture.From.RowOff = Pixel2MTU(2);

                picture.SetSize(width, height);
                if (position > 0)
                {
                    picture.SetPosition(0, position);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the size of those images? Do you know which statement takes the most time? Are you CPU/Memory or IO bound?

Comment: Size of images is not too big: 100x100px... the most time takes statement:
`using (ExcelPicture picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(name, image))`
CPU/Memory/IO - look good...

Comment: 100x100 for a gif is a different size in bytes for an PNG/TIFF/Uncompressed JPEG

Comment: I use JPEG, size - from 2 to 60KB

Comment: I have made a test with one small image (1KB) in a loop and situation was the same. So, to be honest, I think that is a problem with EPPlus library, not my code or my images

Comment: Can you try the other overload of AddPicture? So do `ws.Drawings.AddPicture(name, new FileInfo(filePath))` (you don't need the `image` var anymore in that case). That overload takes a slightly different path and by the looks of it, it doesn't create an extra tempfile. The ExcelPicture class is riddled with `Flush` calls so I wouldn't have high hopes on reaching tremendous speed there

Comment: There also is an issue open on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/10

Comment: @rene - I tried your solution with the other overload - unfortunately this doesn't change anything. I read this topic on github but there is no answer for my question.

Comment: You're out of luck then, unless you fancy to dig in that github issue and fix it in their code.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that while AddPicture has improved speed after the latest update - however setting the row and column offset of the picture is getting progressively slower. And when i analysed the source code it seems for each of this property lot of background work is happening on xml.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, I have a solution, that is, I can calculate the size of each picture ,then calculate the row height according to the picture size, and adjust the height of the entire workbook according to their row height calculated from above info. finally add the picture,

in short ,set the desired rows height before you add any picture.

I hope it will be useful to you

Comment: I think Jan Källman can do an update in inner epplus according to this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30805865)